# how to print json array in html return by node.js

Tags: json, node.js

i return the array from node.js 
reading xml content from txt file and store in array send to html page using ajax method how do this task.

```
  xml2js = require('xml2js');
    fs = require('fs');
    var arr={};

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

        fs.readFile('D:/test.txt', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
               arr=result.Cluster.Array[0].String;    

        });
    });

    app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
      res.json({ message: arr });                    //passing array data
    });
```

how to display in html page current i used. But i get whole  data in console log not able to display in html page get message undefined :

```
  $.ajax({
      url: '/test',
      complete: function(data) {
        JSON.stringify(data);
     console.log(data.message);
      // document.write(data.message);

     for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     {
         document.write(data.message[i].Val);
     $('#did').append('<h1>'+data.message[i].Name+'</h1>');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a ReadStream, and stream it into your httpResponse

```
    stream = fs.createReadStream "path/to/file.json"
    stream.pipe(res)
```

Comment: i read the data above define function but not able to display in another html page but i see data in console log.